# Enviar arquivos via FTP com PHP

Tags: php, upload, ftp

Estou com o seguinte código em PHP para UPLOAD de arquivos em PHP e enviar para um servidor externo via FTP. Entretanto, ele me retorna o seguinte erro quando faço o UPLOAD:

```
Warning: ftp_put(): Illegal PORT command. in /var/www/protocolo/teste/envia.php on line 26
```

O que pode ser?

```html
<?php
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
$ftp_server = "meuhostftp.com.br";
$ftp_username   = "root";
$ftp_password   =  "root";


$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "Conectado a $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else
{
  echo "Não foi possível conectar com $ftp_username\n";
}

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];

$remote_file_path = "/var/www/html/teste/".$file;

ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_BINARY);

ftp_close($conn_id);

echo "\n\nConexão encerrada";

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode testar habilitar o modo passivo no FTP:

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Antes de começar o *ftp_put*:

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); // habilitar o modo passivo do FTP...
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Ahhh cara. Muito obrigado. Resolveu meu problema. kkk o arquivoi foi como uma bala pro outro servidor.